# How can I see just my posts in my Tumblr dashboard so I can easily go back and make edits to posts?

Tags: tumblr

Or any other way where I can easily find one of my older posts to make an edit. Only way I've seen to do it is from the dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

Found it: on the right side in your dashboard under yourtumblrname.tumblr.com it lists the # of posts you have -- click that and it'll filter.

Answer (score 4):

There is a link on the left with X number of posts.
You will find the mass editor there.
[image: Tumblr link]

Comment: Oh, I see you found it.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore right?

Answer (score 0):

As of 5/2019
Click lightning bolt icon to open the Activity panel.
On the right side, at the bottom of the list there in small text it says "Mass Post Editor" That's what you're looking for now.

Answer (score 0):

July 2020: For me I've been searching and finally found the answer. Basically if you want to edit old posts without having to scroll forever down your posts through the dashboard, you can just go to mass post editor on the right side when you click the person icon(top right corner). In the mass post editor, you can navigate easily through your old posts by filtering it by months/years on the top of the page. Once you've found the post you want to edit, open it in a new tab. You also have to be logged in, or else it won't work. Once you've opened the post in a new tab, you'll see a bunch of icons in the top right corner again. (reblog,embed,a pencil which means to EDIT,a trash can to delete the post,and a house to take you back to your dashboard) CLICK ON THE PENCIL. Then you'll be able to edit that specific post!
Hopefully I explained it well enough!