# Is there a quick way to edit a specific Tumblr post?

Tags: tumblr

I'm at a specific post of my Tumblr blog (its permalink). I want to edit it. Is there a quick way to do that? I don't see an Edit link anywhere. When I try to search for it in my dashboard by switching to the tumblelog in the dropdown and searching ("This Tumblelog") for words in the title or body of my specific post, it does not show up.

I know about [this other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14146/how-can-i-see-just-my-posts-in-my-tumblr-dashboard-so-i-can-easily-go-back-and-ma), but I don't want to see *all* my posts. I have far too many and want to edit a specific one that is very far back in time. Currently I have to scroll past *all* my other posts to get to it, and this is very annoying and time-consuming.

Is there a quicker way to do this? Am I searching my tumblelog wrong? Or is this a bug in Tumblr?

**Update**: I would much prefer a way to do it in the Dashboard so that I can also moderate notes.

Comment: What do you mean by "moderating notes"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mehper's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15636/354) no longer works, as [Kirk Woll](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/10002/kirk-woll) mentions. As of Feb 2015, you need the following URL to edit:

```
https://www.tumblr.com/edit/<post_id>?redirect_to=%2Fblog%2F<blog_name>
```

Replacing < post_id> with your post ID # (example: 406783219) and replacing < blog_name> with the domain of your blog, without the tumblr.com part (example: staff).

```
https://www.tumblr.com/edit/406783219?redirect_to=%2Fblog%2Fstaff
```

Obviously, you have to be logged in to your account first, and have the appropriate edit permissions.

Comment: I would like to add modifications `https://www.tumblr.com/edit/<post_id>/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F<blog_name>.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F<post_id>`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a quick and easy way.

If your post has the following permalink

```
http://account.tumblr.com/post/1239802
```

then your edit page is here:

```
http://account.tumblr.com/edit/1239802
```

You just change "post" in the URL to "edit". Note that this does not work if you put something after the post ID (for instance: `http://...../1239802/my-post`).

Comment: This works, but only if you remove the slug (text after the ID). Thanks! Now I'm going to have to accept this answer w/o finding out how to moderate notes :( Maybe that's another question...

Comment: @Jonathan Tran: Yep, it works only if you remove the slug (text after the ID). I've already stated that in the last part of my answer. That seems like the only way.

Comment: There is nothing about this answer that works at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I found this bookmarklet that does the job:
http://blog.tjp.hu/post/409753541/szajmon-tumblr-edit-post-bookmarklet

Answer (score 1):

If you want a link on each post to edit it, you can use this in your custom theme:

```
<a href="https://www.tumblr.com/edit/{PostID}?redirect_to=%2Fblog%2F<blog_name>">edit</a>
```

The `{PostID}` will automatically be filled in with the correct number by Tumblr.

Sadly, I'm not aware of any way to automatically put your blog's name in the URL, so be sure to replace `<blog_name>`!

It shouldn't be a security issue; anyone could manually create that URL, and Tumblr's usual security systems should protect your pages.  That said, you might want to use a bit of CSS to hide it, as it's useless noise to your readers. I'm using this in my CSS (the `<style>` section):

```
.hideme {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.hideme:hover {
    opacity: 1 ;
}
```

and this as my link:

```
<span class="hideme"><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/edit/{PostID}?redirect_to=%2Fblog%2FANONYMIZED">edit</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since sjazmon's bookmarklet is not functional anymore, I created a new bookmarklet for the job:

```
function(){
var usrid = location.href.slice(8, location.href.search('.tumblr')); var pstid = location.href.replace('https://'+usrid+'.tumblr.com/post/', ''); var numid = pstid.split(/\//)[0]; window.open('https://www.tumblr.com/edit/'+numid+'/?redirect_to=/blog/'+usrid)
}();
```

I hope this is helpful. The complete tutorial is [here on my blog](https://60b3r.tumblr.com/post/619332064034029568/60b3rs-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88-edit-post-bookmarklet).